# Send AT commands programatically to ESP8266 without Arduino

Tags: serial, esp8266

Let me explain my question in more details. I want to use ESP8266-01 as standalone micro-controller for my project. I don't want to use Arduino or any other board with that.
Using Arduino i can use two of the pins as software serial and can send different AT commands to ESP module to ESP's Tx and Rx pins, but now what I want is to eliminate the need to Arduino.

What I want to do is to to program ESP itself to toggle mode from AP mode to Host mode on press of a push button. for that I has to send AT commands to ESP from the code while i will write to the ESP itself. Is there any way to achieve the same.

I tried searching a lot but what I found everywhere is how to send AT commands from Arduino.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use AT commands. You install the esp8266 boards package and program the esp8266 as if it were an Arduino. That means learning the esp8266 WiFi API which has plenty of examples included.

- https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, I connected ESP using FTDI, and now I am programming it using Arduino IDE. Is there any provision such as software serial or anything like that ?

Comment: For doing what?